# functions in C#

Tags: c#, function

As in c # to create and then call the function? In C + + do so:

```
int func (int value) 
{ 
   value +=2;
}
```

But as is done in c #?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Please rephrase.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the same function translated in C#:

```
public void Func(ref int value) 
{
   // Parameter is passed by reference so any modification
   // to the value will propagate to the caller
   value +=2;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
int value = 5;
Func(ref value); // value is now 7
```

---

UPDATE:

If as an alternative you don't want to reflect the modifications made to the `value` parameter outside the function you could declare it like this:

```
public void Func(int value) 
{ 
   // Parameter is passed by value so any modification
   // to the value will not propagate to the caller
   value +=2;
}
```

And call like this:

```
int value = 5;
Func(value); // value is still 5
```

Comment: That may be the intended goal, but that's not what the OP's function is doing. `value` isn't passed by reference in his code.

Comment: the OP's snippet wouldn't even compile though would it?

Comment: @Blindy, I agree with you and updated my answer to reflect your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Considering your example is wrong... well, anyway.

```
public void func(ref int value)
{
  value+=2;
}
```

Comment: I am aware of that. His example doesn't make sense either.